# PhpWord не записывает в файл[Решено]

Tags: php, phpword

Всем здравствуйте. Продолжение темы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414612/Функции-file-put-contents/1414624#1414624

Не удается записать данные в файл из БД с помощью PhpWord. (Данные в переменные поступают)

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
require "./vendor/autoload.php";
include "connect.php";

$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('./title_for_report.doc');

$uploadDir = __DIR__;


$numb = filter_var(trim($_POST['nom_kab']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$filename = 'Отчет-о-кабинете-'.$numb.'. Дата и время-'. date('Y-m-d H-i-s') . '.doc';

$kab11 = isset($_POST['11kab']);
$kab15 = isset($_POST['15kab']);
$kab21 = isset($_POST['21kab']);
$kab28 = isset($_POST['28kab']);
$kab36 = isset($_POST['36kab']);
$kab37 = isset($_POST['37kab']);
$kab46 = isset($_POST['46kab']);
$kab47 = isset($_POST['47kab']);

if ($kab11 || $kab15 || $kab21 || $kab28 || $kab36 || $kab37 || $kab46 || $kab47) {
    $report_select="SELECT `name_computer`, `computer`, `motherboard`, `display`, `multimedia`,
        `data_storage`, `input`, `network`, `peripherals`, `bios` FROM `mat-tehn` where `kab`='$numb'";
    $report=mysqli_query($mysqli, $report_select);
    $report_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($report);

    $name_computer = $report_info['name_computer'];
    $computer = $report_info['computer'];
    $motherboard = nl2br($report_info['motherboard']);
    $display = $report_info['display'];
    $multimedia = $report_info['multimedia'];
    $data_storage = $report_info['data_storage'];
    $input = $report_info['input'];
    $network = $report_info['network'];
    $peripherals = $report_info['peripherals'];
    $bios = $report_info['bios'];
        

    $writen = $document -> setValue('motherboard',$motherboard);

    if ($writen){
        echo "<h3><center>Данные успешно загружены. <a href='../report.html'>Вернуться</h3></center>";
    }else {
        echo "<h3><center>Ошибка. <a href='../report.html'>Вернуться.</h3></center>";
 }
}
?>
```

[image: Структура папки]

[image: Структура .doc документа(пока что не готовый до конца, тк решил сначала проверить, как работает данная библиотека)]

Comment: Простите но я не вижу в вашем коде, где бы вы сохраняли данные :) Ознакомьтесь с [документацией](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) до начала работы с библиотекой.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо, и в правду глупо.  Данные записываются, но есть одно "но", в поле таблицы имеется несколько строк записей, для их 'разделения' использовал nl2br, но при его использование, выдает ошибку уже в самом .doc файле. Знаю, что nl2br используется для разрыва строки в хтмл страницах. Поэтому хотелось бы спросить, есть ли какой-нибудь "аналог", реализующий  такую же функцию, но только в MSWord?

Comment: Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, помог следующий код     $motherboard = str_replace("\r\n", '</w:t><w:br/><w:t xml:space="preserve">',$data', еще раз спасибо за помощь, @ВладимирКлыков